# Word that emcompasses both embassies and consulates

Tags: word-choice, single-word-requests

At [Wikivoyage](https://en.wikivoyage.org/wiki/Main_Page) we are looking for a word to describe any kind of official representation office of a country in another country.

It mostly means embassies and consulates, even though sometimes they have special names for various political reasons.

Examples:

- [Embassy of Mexico, Berlin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Embassy_of_Mexico,_Berlin)
- [Consulate-General of Russia in New York City](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Consulate-General_of_Russia_in_New_York_City)
- [High Commission of Canada to the United Kingdom](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/High_Commission_of_Canada_to_the_United_Kingdom)
- [Taipei Economic and Cultural Office in Houston](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taipei_Economic_and_Cultural_Office_in_Houston) ([more names](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_diplomatic_missions_of_Taiwan))

We are looking for a **short word** (3 to 10 letters maybe?) to be used in the wikicode, it will be seen by editors but not by visitors, which means we are ready to compromise exactitude for shortness, if necessary.

Comment: How short must this candidate word be (i.e. what is the max. character count)?

Comment: It’s going to have to be something like *consular sites/seats*.

Comment: @ErikKowal: Added requested information to my question, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I propose:

le·ga·tion

: a group of government officials sent to work in a foreign country; **also : the building where such a group works**. [Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/legation)

The plural has nine letters, but hey - diplomatic missions has 18 plus a space.

Another possibility might be to cut the *diplomatic* and simply use the word *mission*. It's defined as:

> b :  a permanent embassy or legation [MW](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/mission)
>
> c. A permanent diplomatic office abroad. [TFD](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/mission)

That'd be an eight letter plural.

Comment: Some people here dislike the term and argue it is no longer in use... checking Wikipedia I indeed see *"a legation was a diplomatic representative office lower than an embassy"*: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legation

Comment: @NicolasRaoul - Then you may have to decide which constraint is more important: brevity of expression versus using an obsolete or disfavoured term.

Comment: @ErikKowal: It seems so indeed! I am still hoping that someone will come up with a great word that fits the requirements... by the way feel free to propose other answers even if it does not fit in 10~20 characters :-)

Comment: @Nicolas Check my edit to see if that suggestion might work for you. Also, if you're now fine with 10+ characters you might want to edit that into your initial question to clarify it for everyone.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps ***Official representation overseas*** might work (its length is 32 chars., including 2 spaces). I realize that the *Official representation* component is rather similar to your original description, but that might actually be an advantage if your 10-20 character limitation has been lifted.